# Randomly Creating Categorical Variables in R

Tags: r, random, categorical-data

How can I randomly create categorical variables in R?

Below I randomly create a variable that is composed of the values "m" and "f", which stand for male and female.

```
sex <- sample(letters[c(6,13)], 10000, replace=TRUE)
```

But how can I enter the values in words, as in "male" and "female"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
sample(c('male', 'female'), 10000, replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to create a vector of the string values, clearly specifying the categories to be randomly created, and then input this vector into the `sample()` function.  Specific proportions for the randomly generated data set can be defined here also, which can be helpful.

Example code:

```
STRINGS <- c("Male","Female")
STRINGS <- sample(STRINGS, 25, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
```